# Is it possible to group selector with :not() negation pseudo-class?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is it possible to group selectors (e.g. p, li) with :not() negation pseudo-class? (Something like this, just to give an idea):

```
p, li a:not(.tags, .promo):link{ 
    border-bottom: 1px solid; 
    padding: 0 0 0.06rem 0
   }
p, li a:not(.tags, .promo):visited,
p, li a:not(.tags, .promo):hover,
p,li a:not(.tags, .promo):active { 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc
   }
```

Please note: not multiple arguments, but group the p and li.

Comment: No, it does not. Please, read my quetion.

Comment: Ow you want to group the `p` and `li`? Sorry, misread.

Comment: yes why not. But are you sure? What you are doing there is having 2 rules setting both the same css property. Plus you are repeating the p element type. You just need to list it once in a list of comma separated selectors. But maybe you meant to say `p or li having as descendants anchor not being .tags nor .promo when :link`. In that case no. You need to say `p a:not(-----), li a:not(-----)`

Comment: Was your intention to apply the not to `p` and the `li a` or just the `li a`? if just the `li a` then your code should work as is

Comment: Grouping the `p`, `a` and `li` so the `not()` works on all 3 of them, is not possible using plain CSS. You should use a `,` with double selectors.

Comment: I'd like to have the `a href` of both `p` and `li` applied to those hover effects

Comment: You're better of applying a class to those elements and then use `.targets:not(..):link`

Comment: @Diego D : `p a:not(-----), li a:not(-----)` is what I need. There's not a shorter way to do it?

Comment: No, unless you use a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to combine multiple HTML tags with a pseudo-class like `not()` with pure CSS.

<sub>**Note**: I say *pure*, since using a CSS pre-processor like Sass, this would be possible</sub>

---

The only way of achieving the same, with fewer lines of CSS is to apply a class to the elements you wish to include

So instead of

```css
p  a:not(.something),
li a:not(.something) {
    color: red;
}
```

Use a class:

```css
.target:not(.something) {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class='target'>
    <a>Link</a>
</p>

<ol class='target'>
    <li>
        <a>Link</a>
    </li>
</ol>
```